# Laravel returning error when using header

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to download a file, but i keep getting the following error

```
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Http\Response::header(), 1 passed in /home/vagrant/projects/name/app/Http/Controllers/InitialController.php on line 178 and at least 2 expected
```

The code im using is as follows:

```
return (new Response($file, 200))
    ->header('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
    ->header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.gz"');
```

It works fine if i leave out the Content-Disposition line, but when i add it i get the error.

Any help would be grand.

Peace!

Answer (score 3):

because You provide whole header as first argument, should be

```
->header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="filename.gz"');
```